# What's the best way to get a file's basename from an URI, in Vala?

Tags: uri, vala

I can think of two ways: first, I could just manipulate the string itself; strip everything that precedes the last "/". Or, I could use the URI to get a File object, then call query_info().get_display_name().

The first doesn't feel right, while the second results in two objects being created. What is the best practice to follow here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second way (using GLib.File) is probably the most robust, but...

If what you have is really a path, not a URI (e.g.., /home/foo/bar not file:///home/foo/bar) you can just use GLib.Path.get_basename:

```
GLib.Path.get_basename ("/home/foo/bar");
```

Because characters in a URI can be encoded (e.g., %20 instead of a space), if you really have a URI you may need to unescape the string first:

```
GLib.Path.get_basename (GLib.Uri.unescape_string ("file:///home/foo/bar%20baz"));
```

Comment: +1 for making the point that which way you should use depends on how much robustness you need, i.e. how much you can trust your input. Let me make the point again in this comment, only less subtly ;-)